# filter array having specific pattern in php

Tags: php, arrays, string, array-filter

i have the following array with 10,000+ entries

```
1895] => CHQ N SUMEET KHUITAN DEP BY VAIBHAV  MONEY TRANS                                
    [1896] => CR
    [1897] =>            85,000.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    TCI           01/12/13    01/12/13  
    [1898] => 
    [1899] =>      2         S32324176    01/12/13
    [1900] =>                                              
    [1901] => <444209603509>MY FINANCE LTD                                              
    [1902] => CR
    [1903] =>          8,00,000.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    TBI           01/12/13    01/12/13  
    [1904] => 
    [1905] =>      2         S32323871    01/12/13
    [1906] =>                                              
    [1907] => EARTH SUB REMIT, BOHORA TAR                                                     
    [1908] => CR
    [1909] =>          2,00,000.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    TCI           01/12/13    01/12/13  
    [1910] => 
    [1911] =>   1319         S32321414    01/12/13
    [1912] =>       1000786233                             
    [1913] => INWARD CLEARING NPR                                                             
    [1914] => DR
    [1915] =>       1,00,00,000.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    LI            01/12/13    01/12/13  
    [1916] => 
    [1917] =>      2            DC9032    01/12/13
    [1918] =>                                              
    [1919] => HAMRO BIKASH BANK                                                               
    [1920] => CR
    [1921] =>         13,00,000.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    TCI           01/12/13    01/12/13  
    [1922] => 
    [1923] =>      1            DC7192    01/12/13
    [1924] =>                                              
    [1925] => SP TRADING CASH DEPOSIT                                                         
    [1926] => CR
    [1927] =>            36,140.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    CNR           01/12/13    01/12/13  
    [1928] => 
    [1929] =>      2         S32318770    01/12/13
    [1930] =>                                              
    [1931] => <444990698490>good FINANCE LTD                                              
    [1932] => CR
    [1933] =>         35,00,000.00         Not Available           Not Available    Not Available           Not Available    TBI           01/12/13    01/12/13
```

From this entries i want consider the array which start with '<' preserving their original index

i.e

```
[1901] => <444209603509>MY FINANCE 
[1931] => <444990698490>good FINANCE
```

i did the folowing

```
 foreach($arr as $key=>$val){
            if(substr($val,0,1)=='<')
                $new_arr[$key]=$val;
        }
        print_r($new_arr);
```

I really slowed down the script, dont we have any alternative like **array_filter**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try array_filter in PHP. The function checks whether the array value starts with `<`.

```
function myFilter($val){
            $val = trim($val);
            return ($val[0]==='<');
}


array_filter($array,'myFilter');
```